# Installshield pre-requisites required for dacpac deployment

Tags: deployment, installshield, prerequisites, dacpac

What are the install shield prerequisites required for dacpac deployment? I can add the DLLs individually but would be nice if there was a built in MSI installer that includes the required SQL server  files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer for the latest RTM version of the dacpac deployment framework can be downloaded here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48203

There are two prerequisites that should also be downloaded and installed: SQLSysClrTypes.msi and SQLDOM.msi.  These are available from the SQL Server 2014 Feature Pack download page here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42295

If you're installing these on a machine with a 64-bit OS (and most everyone is these days), we recommend installing both the x86 and x64 versions.